# Is this correct grammar with the semi-colon

Tags: grammaticality, grammar, punctuation

This sentence is from my essay. Is the semi-colon correct?

> His most famous residence is the Kaufmann Residence; esteemed for its use of organic architecture with Japanese architectural components to create harmony with the residence and nature.

Comment: While most proof reading questions are off topic, this one is fine (on that front) because it specifies the part of the sentence which is an issue.

Comment: @simchona: ...and it is therefore not proofreading.

Comment: @Cerberus: ...but it is perilously close to "writing advice", I feel.

Comment: @FumbleFingers: Whatever that means, and whatever would be wrong with that...

Comment: @Cerberus: As ever, I don't care much for questions on punctuation, which doesn't really exist in what I think of as "real" English. That's to say, the spoken form. (But I did upvote your answer - partly because obviously it was *right*, but mainly because of the "writing advice" that OP would do better to rephrase such a ????? sentence! :)

Answer (score 6):

No, I'm afraid you need to replace it with a comma or recast the sentence (I would choose the latter). You'd normally only use a semicolon if the part that comes after is an independent sentence. This is not one of the typical exceptions.

Answer (score 4):

The general construction your sample exemplifies, in learned written English, is:

> [Clause establishing topic], [Comment on topic]

In this case, the topic is "the Kaufmann Residence," and you have a comment consisting of an adjective phrase ("esteemed for..."). The comment need not be a full clause. Another example, from a piece of fiction occurring in the *New Yorker*:

> She had a room on the side of a house, wobbly wooden stairs leading up.

When you use a semicolon to separate a topic-establishing clause and a comment, the comment must consist of a full clause. That is why it looks bad as it is.